# Insert javascript into different page on same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to insert some javascript into a page on my server, from a different page.  The 1st page will be loaded into an iframe.  I would like to insert some css styles to that page (in the iframe) from the page hosting the iFrame.  is there a jQuery script I can use to do this?

Something like.
   page1->page2 iframe.  page2 script for styles-> page1 within the iframe

```
    <body>
    <!--<div id="left_col"></div>-->
    <div id="middle_col">
        <!--header-->
        <div id="header">
            <p>iFrame Example</p>
        </div>      
                <div id="entry">
                    <p>Enter your URL</p>
                    <textarea id="mytextarea" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>

                        <a title="Check Me Out!" id="btn-wrap">
                            <span class="title">Click to view site</span>

                            <div id="info">
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Don't forget</strong>
                                    <strong>the "http://"</strong>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                </div>
             <br/>
             <br/>
            <iframe id="myframe" src="http://johnverber.com/simple.html">
            </iframe>
    </div>
    <!--<div id="right_col"></div>-->
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        positionAd();
     });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        positionAd();
    });

    var positionAd = function() {
        var WINDOW_WIDTH = $(window).width();
        var WINDOW_HEIGHT = $(window).height();
        var BOX_WIDTH = $('#middle_col').width();
        var BOX_HEIGHT = $('#middle_col').height();

        $('#middle_col').css({"left": (WINDOW_WIDTH - BOX_WIDTH)/2, "top" : (WINDOW_HEIGHT - BOX_HEIGHT)/2});
        }

    $('#btn-wrap').click(function() {
                    var urlVal = $('#mytextarea').val();
                    if(urlVal.match("?_myTag")){
                        document.getElementById('myframe').src = urlVal;
                    }
                    else{
                        var addTag = urlVal.concat("?_myTag");
                        document.getElementById('myframe').src = addTag;
                    }
    });

    $('#myframe').contents().find("head").append("<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="addStyles.css" />");

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think pasting in some code would be helpful, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's **[`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)** to access the `iframe`'s inner DOM. It's quite trivial from there:

```
$("#iframe_id").contents().find("head").append("<script>..scripts..</script>");
//or
$("#iframe_id").contents().find("head").append("<style>..styles..</style>");
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: It worked for a minute...it threw all my align center stylings off, now I can't get it to work at all.  With or without align center.  Any thoughts on that?  I will add my code to the original questions.

Comment: @Verber That must be a separate issue -- yep, providing your code would be useful.

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure why it's not working.  I have the $("#myframe")....etc at the bottom of the <body> with my other scripts

Comment: @Verber Use single quotes inside the `append` parameter instead: `.append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='addStyles.css' />")`.

Comment: Nope...it's still not working, which is strange cause it was working before.

Comment: @Verber You sure? make sure you're using single quotes, or escaping the quotes inside if they're same type of the outer ones.

Comment: this is what I'm using: $('#myframe').contents().find("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="addStyles.css" />'); within the script tags in the body of the page

Comment: @Verber That should work. Maybe it's that you're not closing a previous tag in your `head`. This isn't an issue with adding the `link`, it must be with what's surrounding it.

Comment: I see whats happening.  It's including the style...but it's commenting it out so when I view in Firebug it says <!--<link rel.....etc>-->

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is what finally ended up working:

```
$("#iframe_id").contents().find("head").html("<style>..styles..</style>");
```